# Service Connection in Azure Devops for 2 Subscriptions

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-extensions

I am using Azure Devops Pipelines. In my CI yaml and calling a powershell script. Within Powershell i am reading details of an existing resource say storage account sitting in subscription X, and creating an exact replica in subscription Y. We have created a Service connection using service principal of X  in Azure devops and are using in our CI pipeline. Not aware of how to include Y Service Principal so that resource can be created in Y subscription.

Anything can be handled at Azure side? Please suggest the way.

Comment: 2 subscriptions are Azure subscriptions

Comment: You can create two service connections of two subscriptions on DevOps, and then use two tasks, the first task is get information from subscription X, the second task is create resource in subcription Y. Does this meet your requirements?

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT  yes i understand this can be done. Still 1 Service connection for both Subscriptions not possible?

Comment: @JemHah Of course not.

Comment: @JemHah You can have a service principal that spans multiple subscriptions as long as those subscriptions share an AD Tenant.